# Get customer vault card details

Tags: magento2

How do we load the saved cards (vault) of a registered customer in Magento 2? This is how it's done in Magento 1:

```
$savedCards = Mage::getModel('tokenbase/card')->getCollection();
$savedCards->addFieldToFilter('active', 1)
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer_id);
$card = $savedCards->getFirstItem();
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

```
protected $session;
protected $paymenttokenmanagement;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Vault\Api\PaymentTokenManagementInterface $paymenttokenmanagement,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session
) {
    $this->paymenttokenmanagement = $paymenttokenmanagement;
    $this->session = $session;
}
```

Then you can use following:

```
// Get the customer id
$customerId = $this->session->getCustomer()->getId();
// Card list
$cardList = $this->paymenttokenmanagement->getListByCustomerId($customerId);
```